# Alias for using SELECT result in WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a query on which I use a WHERE IN SELECT. Here is the query:

```
SELECT tville_id, tville_nom, tville_etat
FROM TAB_ZONE   
INNER JOIN TAB_VILLES ON tville_id = tzone_cidade
WHERE tzone_unidade1 = 1 
   OR tzone_unidade2 = 1 
   OR tzone_unidade3 = 1 
   OR tzone_unidade1 IN (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1)
   OR tzone_unidade2 IN (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1)
   OR tzone_unidade3 IN (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1)
ORDER BY tville_etat, tville_nom
```

It works, but as you can see I have three time the "SELECT tunidade_id" statement in the WHERE part. Is there a way to use the result of this SELECT  as an alias, so perform it only one time? (and is it usefull?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In [MariaDB 10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-102) you can use [common-table expressions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/common-table-expressions-overview) for [this purpose](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/common-table-expressions-overview/#use-case-2-multiple-use-of-cte).

```
WITH cte_tunidade AS (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1)
SELECT tville_id, tville_nom, tville_etat
FROM TAB_ZONE   
INNER JOIN TAB_VILLES ON tville_id = tzone_cidade
WHERE tzone_unidade1 = 1 
   OR tzone_unidade2 = 1 
   OR tzone_unidade3 = 1 
   OR tzone_unidade1 IN (SELECT * FROM cte_tunidade)
   OR tzone_unidade2 IN (SELECT * FROM cte_tunidade)
   OR tzone_unidade3 IN (SELECT * FROM cte_tunidade)
ORDER BY tville_etat, tville_nom
```

Whether it will bring you a noticeable performance improvement -- I guess the best way to find out is to try; but at the very least a query is better maintainable this way.

Comment: As 10.2 seems no to be stable, I'll just write this on a paper for next MariaDB update. Thanks!

Comment: 10.2 GA (a.k.a. stable) should be released very soon now, it's the matter of days.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified, but in my understanding something like this should work:

```
SELECT tville_id, tville_nom, tville_etat
FROM TAB_ZONE   
INNER JOIN TAB_VILLES ON tville_id = tzone_cidade
JOIN (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1 UNION SELECT 1) x on x.tunidade_id in (tzone_unidade1, tzone_unidade2, tzone_unidade3)
ORDER BY tville_etat, tville_nom
```

Answer (score 0):

If not wrong the below conditions can be merged to one

```
OR tzone_unidade1 IN (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1)
OR tzone_unidade2 IN (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1)
OR tzone_unidade3 IN (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1)
```

To something like

```
OR (tzone_unidade1,tzone_unidade2,tzone_unidade3) IN (SELECT tunidade_id FROM TAB_UNIDADE WHERE tunidade_parent = 1)
```

Comment: Unless MySQL doesn't follow the standard that's not going to work.

Comment: After testing using MariaDB, as say shawnt00, this is not working. :(

Comment: The syntax which you had in mind would be `OR (a,b,c) IN (SELECT x,x,x FROM ...)` -- note `x` repeated three times, -- but the logic is wrong. This clause means `OR (a IN (SELECT x FROM ...) AND b = a AND c = a)` (not taking into account `NULL`s, for simplicity), which is not the same as the original clause at all.

Comment: The logic may be the other direction - "tunidade_id in (tzone_unidade1, tzone_unidade2, tzone_unidade3)" - I've posted another reply

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to *not* splay an array across columns.  Instead have multiple rows in another table.  With such, you can avoid the repeated query, CTEs, performance issues, etc.